# How to preview input selected image after browser refresh in jquery

Tags: jquery, file, input

I want to preview selected image after browser refresh.

When I refresh browser input selected image preview not show. But when I select new image the preview is show.

How can I solved this problem?
I am using this code

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the query `input.files[0]`returns false at the begin.

Comment: after browser refresh this function will call only when an image is selected. that's why it's not worked on browser refresh

Comment: Hi, Alive... image is selected after browser refresh but preview not show.... Would you please help me?

Comment: CAN YOU CREATE AN EXAMPLE LINK YOUR PROBLEM (LIKE FIDDLE)?

Comment: Im using using this on wordpress edit profile section

Comment: Fiddle doesn't keep input selected imaga after browser refresh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use local storage. HTML local storage; better than cookies. After refresh your browser script will check the local storage data if found then load the file/files. Please follow-
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp